# Django, pandas, excel: uploading files, parsing them with pandas in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-views

I have a big command-line script for parsing data in Excel (with pandas) and I want to wrap it with Django. I've tried both uploading files thru request.FILES and pandas, but get stuck on uploading file and, for example, saving it (not necessarily but just to check the upload for now).

Haven't had any problems with other apps on Django which didn't require uploading and parsing anything external and thought that would be much easier..:)

I've also tried Redirecting, doesn't really work, the only redirect which is actually happening is action in the form tag..

Here are the code snippets:

views.py:

```
def uploads(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            excel_file = request.FILES['document']
            excel_file.save()
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")
```

forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('document', )
```

index.html:

```
<form
              action="{% url 'reports'%}"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
            >
              {% csrf_token %}
              <span>
                Upload .xlsx file <input type="file" name="document" />
              </span>
              <button type="submit">
                SUBMIT
              </button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I had another function in views.py leading to the same url route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must save the form's content actually:

```
form.save()
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't really change anything :(
I've tried it with HttpResponseRedirect too, no luck..

Comment: I think that and adding the form to the template like this will do the trick:           

<form
              action="{% url 'reports'%}"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
            >
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }}
              <button type="submit">
                SUBMIT
              </button>
            </form>

Comment: not really.. I wanna keep the second Upload button (an input tag), and it won't work together.. :-(